# Django-comments and legacy database? "OperationalError: no such table"

Tags: django, django-comments, legacy-database

I'm using a [legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/) (in addition to a 'normal' database), defined in my `settings.py` :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
                 },
    'articles_database': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles.db'),
 } }
```

and in my `models.py` with:

```
from django.db import models

class ArticlesTable(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    article_type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    article_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    article_number = models.IntegerField(db_column='article_number', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'articles_table'
```

After having installed Django-comments on my Django 1.8.5: I can get a proper form to fill a comment, but clicking on the "Post" button gets this error:

```
OperationalError at /comments/post/

no such table: articles_table
```

with the line for error highlighted:

```
/home/gus/.Envs/python3_django/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_comments/views/comments.py in post_comment

56. target = model._default_manager.using(using).get(pk=object_pk)
```

Apparently, Django-comments didn't find my table inside my database? Is it possible to use a legacy database in fact with Django-comments?

**EDIT:**  I've fixed the model for my legacy database as @Geo Jacob suggested:

```
class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'articles_table'
```

But now I got an error page (provided by Django-comments, not a Debug page):

```
Comment post not allowed (400)
Why: No object matching content-type 'articles.articlestable' and 
object PK '1' exists.

The comment you tried to post to this view wasn't saved because 
something tampered with the security information in the comment 
form. The message above should explain the problem, or you can check 
the comment documentation for more help.
```

Django-comments in the `post_comment` function gets the right model (`ArticlesTable`) but can't find the object???

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `managed=False`

```
class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'articles_table'
```

Now makemigrations or syncdb, then articles_table will be created.

Comment: Now I've got: 
    Comment post not allowed (400)
    Why:  No object matching content-type 'articles.articlestable' and   object PK '1' exists.

    The comment you tried to post to this view wasn't saved because something tampered with the security information in the comment form.